# Работа с масивом который вернет old()

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть select куда записывается перечень тегов к статье

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control entry-tags" name="tags_id[]">
<option></option>
</select>
```

После отправки всей формы в `tags_id[]` записывается массив с перечнем id выбранных тегов. И все бы хорошо, но если форма не проходит валидацию, пользователь возвращается обратно и через функцию `old()` можно получить сохраненные поля, которые ввел пользователь.

Но, мое поле `tags_id[]` является массивом, и если я пытаюсь получить массив таким образом `old('tags_id')` мне выбивает ошибку, что ожидается строка а не массив. Можно конечно так получать `old('tags_id.0')`, `old('tags_id.1')`... но это явно не путь джедая :)

Ну и собственно вопрос, как мне вытянуть этот самый массив на фронтенде, что бы я мог подставить выбранные теги в поле?

Comment: Вы бы код, что ли, показали.

Answer (score 0):

Это и есть выход.

`<form method="post" action="">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="text" name="field[]" value="{{ old('field.0') }}" />
    <input type="text" name="field[]" value="{{ old('field.1') }}" />
    <input type="text" name="field[]" value="{{ old('field.2') }}" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

А вообще, в 21 веке, принято не обновлять страницу, а отправлять формы ajax'ом, тогда и проблемы этой не будет и посетитель вашего сайта вам спасибо скажет за сэкономленный траффик, нервы и время.